# ERROR: cannot update table "book_max" because it does not have a replica identity and publishes updates

Tags: postgresql, sql-update

I am trying to perform an update on a table using temp table.

> Error updating database.  Cause: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: cannot update table "book_max" because it does not have a replica identity and publishes updates
> Hint: To enable updating the table, set REPLICA IDENTITY using ALTER TABLE.

However, I do have a primary key on my temp table.
Below is my query :

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE IF NOT EXISTS bookTemp
                (
                bookId                varchar(50),
                authorId              varchar(50),
                subject             varchar(50),
                index                integer,
                index_id                integer,
                buyer            varchar(50),
                buyerId        varchar(50)

                PRIMARY KEY (bookId, authorId, subject, index, buyer)
                )

  INSERT INTO bookTemp(,,,,,,,)

  update book 
  set bookId = b.bookId,
  authorId = b.authorId,
  subject = b.subject, 
  index = b.index,
  index_id = b.index_id,
  buyer = b.buyer,
  buyerId = b.buyerId
  from bookTemp b
  where ....;
```

I am not sure why it is giving me this error despite the primary key.

Comment: The issue may be that the temp table is not using the primary key as defined during the update.

Comment: There is an incorrectly defined publication (for logical replication) that concerns the table `book`. Read more in [the documentation.](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/logical-replication.html)

Comment: The error is not about your temp table, but about your permanent table.  Does *that* have a primary key defined?

Comment: Hi @jjanes, thanks for your suggestion. Found out that all the partitions were having the primary key except for the  _max table which didnt have any primary key. Though I dont have any idea how did that happen but restoring the primary key worked.